# How to post a body in in java script and ajax to API

Tags: javascript, ajax, outlook-addin

I have some existing code which is run in a MS outlook plugin which authenticates with a backend. I need to update the code to send the user and password as part of body in json doc since we are having issues with users using special char like # etc n the password.

```
function authenticate(host, userid ,password, callback) {
  //replace server url
  var requestUrl
  if (host){
    requestUrl = "https://" + host + "/auth/plugin/" + userid + "/" + password
  }else{
    requestUrl = "https://127.0.0.1/auth/plugin2/" + userid + "/" + password
  }
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: requestUrl,
    body: {userid: "user", password : "myPassword"},
    cache:false
  }).done(function(res){
    callback(res);
  }).fail(function(error){
    callback(null, error);
  });
}
```

i tried the body tag but i don't see anything in my backend that there was a body sent

Comment: What about using `data` insteady of `body`?

Comment: You've could have easily fixed your own problem by looking at the DOCS https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

You can try `data: {userid: "user", password : "myPassword"}`